# The list I have created is not defined according to python

Tags: python

```
def mainMenu():
    print('1. Set up an item for auction\n \n2. Place a bid')
    print('Enter a number from the menu: ')
    menu1 = input('')    

    if menu1 == '1' :
        number = input('Registration number: ')
        name = input('Auctioneer\'s name: ')
        minimum = input('Minimum bid amount: $')
        itemDes = input('Item Description: ')
        bidCount = input('Number of bids: ')
        AuctioneerDet = input('Auctioneer\'s details: ')
        itemNum = random.randint(400,800)
        global itemList
        itemList = []
        itemList.append((minimum, itemDes, AuctioneerDet, bidCount, 
         itemNum))
```

> ```
>    print('Confirm changes?')    
>    print("'y' for yes and 'n' for no")
>    confirm = input('')    
>    if confirm == 'n' or confirm == 'N' :
>        mainMenu()    
>    if confirm == 'y' or confirm == 'Y' :
>        input('Press any key to go back to main menu')
>        mainMenu()
>
>     if menu1 == '2' :
>        print(itemList)
> ```

```
mainMenu()
```

I want to use the elements of itemList in `if menu1 == '2'`, how do i do that? 
It says itemList not defined. 
I want the user to first set up an item for auction by inputting 1 at first and then go back to the main menu and input 2 where the use can view the bid he has placed, but all of this can be done only after the list is defined. I cant work more on this because it keeps saying itemList is not defined. 
The line print(itemList) is just been written to figure out what the issue is. This is not the actual task i want to perform there's more to it which needs to be done on the list.

Comment: What user input are you giving this program? If `1`, then there is no printing. If `2`, then `itemList` is never defined anywhere.

Comment: define your itemList before the if condition. that should solve your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you forgot to define `itemList` before mainMenu. Define itemList before mainMenu and it should work.

```
itemList = []    
def mainMenu():
        print('1. Set up an item for auction\n \n2. Place a bid')
        print('Enter a number from the menu: ')
        menu1 = input('')    

        if menu1 == '1' :
            number = input('Registration number: ')
            name = input('Auctioneer\'s name: ')
            minimum = input('Minimum bid amount: $')
            itemDes = input('Item Description: ')
            bidCount = input('Number of bids: ')
            AuctioneerDet = input('Auctioneer\'s details: ')
            itemNum = random.randint(400,800)
            global itemList
            itemList = []
            itemList.append((minimum, itemDes, AuctioneerDet, bidCount, 
             itemNum))

         if menu1 == '2' :
            print(itemList)

    mainMenu()
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to ensure that itemList is defined before you reach menu1 = '2'

```
 def mainMenu():
    print('1. Set up an item for auction\n \n2. Place a bid')
    print('Enter a number from the menu: ')
    menu1 = input('')
    itemList = []  # <--- Define it here

    if menu1 == '1':
        number = input('Registration number: ')
        name = input('Auctioneer\'s name: ')
        minimum = input('Minimum bid amount: $')
        itemDes = input('Item Description: ')
        bidCount = input('Number of bids: ')
        AuctioneerDet = input('Auctioneer\'s details: ')
        itemNum = random.randint(400, 800)
        global itemList

        itemList.append((minimum, itemDes, AuctioneerDet, bidCount,
                         itemNum))

    if menu1 == '2':
        print(itemList)


mainMenu()
```

Answer (score 1):

You defined `itemList` in case 1

```
    if menu1 == '1' :
             .
             .
             .
        global itemList
-->     itemList = []
        itemList.append((minimum, itemDes, AuctioneerDet, bidCount,
```

From that you can't print `itemList`,

you can define item list outside of the `if statement`.

like this, probably you want to extern `itemList`. just define it as global variable

```
itemList = list()
def mainMenu():
    print('1. Set up an item for auction\n \n2. Place a bid')
    print('Enter a number from the menu: ')
    menu1 = input('')    

    if menu1 == '1' :
        number = input('Registration number: ')
        name = input('Auctioneer\'s name: ')
        minimum = input('Minimum bid amount: $')
        itemDes = input('Item Description: ')
        bidCount = input('Number of bids: ')
        AuctioneerDet = input('Auctioneer\'s details: ')
        itemNum = random.randint(400,800)
        global itemList
        itemList.append((minimum, itemDes, AuctioneerDet, bidCount, 
         itemNum))

     if menu1 == '2' :
        print(itemList)

mainMenu()
```

Answer (score 0):

If the input isn't `'1'`, then `itemList` is never defined. Define it at the start of `mainMenu()`

```
if menu1 == '1' :
        ...
        global itemList  # <-- why is this inside the conditional?
        itemList = []
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you define your list before the first if condition.
    ( if menu=='1')
That would work fine with your code